# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library

Tags: 14.04, qt

I found a lot of problems similar to mine on the web, but still no real solution.
I'm having the annoying

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40806) with this library (version 0x40802)
```

message whenever I try to launch genymotion.
It seems that the problem is either in environment variables or different libraries installed. So, I'm trying to see the output of various commands

1. `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
   returns nothing (actually there is no environment variable with this name.
2. `dpkg -al | grep libqt` (*)
   returns [this list](http://pastebin.com/c70XNgt8)

(*) not sure that is the right command btw

3. Also tried this command
   `echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd ./genymotion`
   and [this is the output](http://pastebin.com/v784bRHM)

4.

```
qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Any idea?

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61841315

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Solved the problem using [this solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2207219&p=13048000#post13048000):

> I have fixed this issue doing the following:
>
> 1. Installing the libs:
>
>    ```
>    apt-get install libxi-dev libxmu-dev
>    ```
> 2. (Re-)moving the Qt libs inside the Genymotion installation
>      directory:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir QtLibs && mv *Qt*.so* QtLibs
>    ```
>
> This last command will make Genymotion use the system's Qt libs.

Comment: i have the same issue with genymotion on ubuntu, and for me when using this command, genymotion cannot execute anymore

Comment: what do you mean by "genymotion cannot execute anymore"?

Comment: basically works but I also add to install qtwebkit and qtsvg version 4

Answer (score 4):

After you have run the following command:`mkdir QtLibs && mv *Qt*.so* QtLibs`

you will need to install system libs. For me it was:

```
    libqtwebkit4
    libqt4-svg
```

You can find out what your system needs by running genymotion from within the command line terminal

Answer (score 2):

This command helped me to start `qtcreator` without that error:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/tools/qtcreator-3.6.1/lib/Qt/lib
```

where `qtcreator-3.6.1` is the installation directory.