# Problem with qt5 while trying to run pgadmin4

Tags: apt, dpkg, qt, pgadmin

I have ubuntu bionic upgrade from xenial recently. After the upgrade, I didn't find my pgadmin4 application, so I reinstalled it. After clicking the pgadmin4 icon, the program not shown. So I try to run it through the terminal, then I found this problem:

```
randyka@orlansoft57-desktop:~$ pgadmin4 
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50501) with this library (version 0x50905)
```

Here is my qtchooser output :

```
root@orlansoft57-desktop:~/Public# qtchooser -list-versions
4
5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

And this my qt5 list of library :

```
root@orlansoft57-desktop:~/Public# dpkg -l qt5* | grep ii
ii  qt5-default:amd64           5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64        Qt 5 development defaults package
ii  qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64        Qt 5 GTK+ 3 platform theme
ii  qt5-qmake:amd64             5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64        Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool
ii  qt5-qmake-bin               5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64        Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool — binary file
```

**EDIT**

Here the output of `ldd`

```
root@orlansoft57-desktop:~# ldd "$(which pgadmin4)" && dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}:${Architecture}\n' libqt5\* | awk '$1=="i" {print $2}' | xargs -r -- apt-cache policy
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdb676b000)
    libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007fabe6fed000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fabe67a6000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fabe603d000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fabe5cb1000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fabe5566000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fabe51dd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fabe4fc5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fabe4bd4000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fabe49a2000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fabe4785000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fabe4566000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fabe4362000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fabe415f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fabe3dc1000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fabe3b35000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fabe3903000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fabe3665000)
    libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60 (0x00007fabe31c4000)
    libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007fabe2e0d000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1 (0x00007fabe2bfc000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fabe28e6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fabe78ff000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fabe26b5000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fabe23ff000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fabe214b000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fabe1f1e000)
    libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007fabe0375000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fabe0103000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fabdfdcb000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fabdfba3000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fabdf99f000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fabdf799000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fabdf584000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fabdf37c000)
libqt53danimation5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dcore5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dextras5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dinput5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dlogic5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dquick5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dquickanimation5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dquickextras5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dquickinput5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dquickrender5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53dquickscene2d5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt53drender5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5bluetooth5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5bluetooth5-bin:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5charts5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5concurrent5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5contacts5:
  Installed: 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7
  Candidate: 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7
  Version table:
 *** 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5core5a:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5dbus5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5designer5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5designercomponents5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5glib-2.0-0:
  Installed: 1.2.0-5
  Candidate: 1.2.0-5
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.0-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.2.0-5
  Candidate: 1.2.0-5
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.0-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5gstreamerquick-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.2.0-5
  Candidate: 1.2.0-5
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.0-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5gstreamerui-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.2.0-5
  Candidate: 1.2.0-5
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.0-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5gstreamerutils-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.2.0-5
  Candidate: 1.2.0-5
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.0-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5gui5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5help5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5keychain1:
  Installed: 0.7.0-3
  Candidate: 0.7.0-3
  Version table:
 *** 0.7.0-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5location5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5location5-plugins:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5multimedia5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5multimedia5-plugins:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5multimediaquick-p5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5multimediawidgets5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5network5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5nfc5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5opengl5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5opengl5-dev:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5organizer5:
  Installed: 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7
  Candidate: 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7
  Version table:
 *** 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5pas1:
  Installed: 2.6~beta-4
  Candidate: 2.6~beta-4
  Version table:
 *** 2.6~beta-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5positioning5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5positioning5-plugins:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5printsupport5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5qevercloud3:
  Installed: 3.0.3+ds-3
  Candidate: 3.0.3+ds-3
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.3+ds-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5qml5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
libqt5quick5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
libqt5quickcontrols2-5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5quickparticles5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
libqt5quicktemplates2-5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5quicktest5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
libqt5quickwidgets5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
libqt5scintilla2-designer:
  Installed: 2.10.2+dfsg-4
  Candidate: 2.10.2+dfsg-4
  Version table:
 *** 2.10.2+dfsg-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5script5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5scripttools5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5sensors5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5serialport5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5sql5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5sql5-ibase:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5sql5-mysql:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5sql5-odbc:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5sql5-psql:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5sql5-sqlite:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5sql5-tds:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5svg5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5test5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5texttospeech5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5versit5:
  Installed: 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7
  Candidate: 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7
  Version table:
 *** 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5versitorganizer5:
  Installed: 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7
  Candidate: 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7
  Version table:
 *** 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5waylandclient5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5waylandcompositor5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5webchannel5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5webengine-data:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5webengine5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5webenginecore5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5webenginewidgets5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5webkit5:
  Installed: 5.212.0~alpha2-7ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.212.0~alpha2-7ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.212.0~alpha2-7ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5websockets5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5webview5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5widgets5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5x11extras5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5xdg3:
  Installed: 3.1.0-5build2
  Candidate: 3.1.0-5build2
  Version table:
 *** 3.1.0-5build2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5xdgiconloader3:
  Installed: 3.1.0-5build2
  Candidate: 3.1.0-5build2
  Version table:
 *** 3.1.0-5build2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5xml5:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5xmlpatterns5:
  Installed: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**EDIT**

Here the output of installed pgadmin4

```
pgadmin4:
  Installed: 3.4-1.pgdg18.04+1
  Candidate: 3.4-1.pgdg18.04+1
  Version table:
 *** 3.4-1.pgdg18.04+1 500
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `ldd "$(which pgadmin4)"` and `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}:${Architecture}\n' libqt5\* | awk '$1=="i" {print $2}' | xargs -r -- apt-cache policy`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks for welcoming me. I have edited my question to add your request, and from my brief view, I did not find any error :(

Comment: I found these `libqt5contacts5`, `libqt5organizer5`, `libqt5versit5`, `libqt5versitorganizer5` using 5.0--- version. Is that the problem?

Comment: Everything looks to be in order from that angle. How did you install `pgadmin4` and did you do it before or after the upgrade to Ubuntu Bionic? What’s the output of `which pgadmin4` and `dpkg-query -S "$(which pgadmin4)" | awk -F '[,:] ' '{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if (!seen[$i]++) print $i; }' | xargs -r -- apt-cache policy`? It would be worth a try to check [package integrity](/a/57728/175814) too.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have updated my question. I installed pgadmin4 after I upgrade my linux to bionic

Comment: The PGAdmin installation looks alright too. Could you please perform [a package sanity check](/a/57728/175814) to verify that nothing replaced the Qt library package files? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster already perform package sanity check and did not find pgadmin4 package. already perform install --reinstall too for broken package and the `Cannot mix incompatible Qt library` error still occurred :(

Comment: In that case I’m out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a duplicate question and answer here in **Ask Ubuntu** but I'm not using the same software: [Cannot mix incompatible Qt library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534415/cannot-mix-incompatible-qt-library)

Solved the problem using [this solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2207219&p=13048000#post13048000)

> I have fixed this issue doing the following:
>
> 1. Installing the libs:
>
>    ```
>    apt-get install libxi-dev libxmu-dev
>    ```
> 2. (Re-)moving the Qt libs inside the Genymotion installation
>      directory
>
>    ```
>    mkdir QtLibs && mv *Qt*.so* QtLibs
>    ```
>
> This last command will make Genymotion use the system's Qt libs.

---

Although the answer has 34 up-votes there are comments below it listing additional steps another user had to take.

Comment: cannot find Qt libs inside pgadmin4 installation directory :(

Comment: Is that the error message word for word? I can't find the same error

Comment: `word for word` what this mean?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the new error message `exactly` like you just did with `word for word`?

Comment: `root@orlansoft57-desktop:/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin# pgadmin4 
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50501) with this library (version 0x50905)
Aborted`

Comment: is that what you mean?

Comment: I thought you had a new error message after trying out the solution in the answer above. I see now it is the same message.

Comment: yup, because I did not find Qt libs folder inside pgadmin4 installation dir